# Difference between slf4j-log4j12 and log4j-over-slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

What's the difference between slf4j-log4j12 and [log4j-over-slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j) and when should each be used?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
log4j-over-slf4j
```

Use this if your code or some libraries you are using uses Log4j directly, but you want to use a **different SLF4J binding than Log4j**. It will route the Log4j API calls to SLF4J to the binding you choose. You need to remove the Log4j library from your classpath and replace it with this dependency.

```
slf4j-log4j12
```

Use this if you **want to use the Log4j 1.2 binding for SLF4J**.

You shouldn't use both of these libraries [at the same time](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j).

Please note also that [Log4j 2 has been released](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html).

Comment: i came across this answer which is approx 3 years old, so in case anyone comes wandering by someone should also mention to be careful which log4j2 version they use to avoid the log4shell vulnerability