# Itext7 bare bones hello world example - how?

Tags: java, itext7

So I've downloaded the compiled itext jar files from https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/latest
and placed them in same folder as the iText example C01E01_HelloWorld.java but when I run

```
javac C01E01_HelloWorld.java
```

I get

```
$ javac C01E01_HelloWorld.java 
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:3: error: package com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf does not exist
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
                              ^
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:4: error: package com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf does not exist
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
                              ^
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:5: error: package com.itextpdf.layout does not exist
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
                          ^
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:6: error: package com.itextpdf.layout.element does not exist
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
                                  ^
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        ^
  symbol:   class PdfWriter
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
                               ^
  symbol:   class PdfWriter
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        ^
  symbol:   class PdfDocument
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                              ^
  symbol:   class PdfDocument
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
                                ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
C01E01_HelloWorld.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
                         ^
  symbol:   class Paragraph
  location: class C01E01_HelloWorld
11 errors
```

I also tried

```
javac -cp /home/user01/itext/demo/ C01E01_HelloWorld.java
```

i.e. where the -cp points to where the iText jar's (and C01E01_HelloWorld.java) is with same result.
How do I get the import lines to know and use the iText jar files?

Or can this not be done in a simple way and need eclipse or maven or ?

So I ran the following without error

```
javac -cp kernel-7.1.13.jar:layout-7.1.13.jar:io-7.1.13.jar C01E01_HelloWorld.java
```

if I left any of the jar files out it resulted in errors related to the missing jar. but when I try

```
java C01E01_HelloWorld
```

I get

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class C01E01_HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/layout/element/IBlockElement
```

I also tried

```
java -cp kernel-7.1.13.jar:layout-7.1.13.jar:io-7.1.13.jar C01E01_HelloWorld
```

which gave slightly different

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C01E01_HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C01E01_HelloWorld
```

so next step yields

```
$ java -cp kernel-7.1.13.jar:layout-7.1.13.jar:io-7.1.13.jar:. C01E01_HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at C01E01_HelloWorld.main(C01E01_HelloWorld.java:21)
```

my source is

```
/*package tutorial.chapter01;*/

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Simple Hello World example.
 */
public class C01E01_HelloWorld {
    
    /* public static final String DEST = "results/chapter01/hello_world.pdf";  */
    
    public static final String DEST = "hello_world.pdf";
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new C01E01_HelloWorld().createPdf(DEST);
    }
    
    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
        //Initialize PDF writer
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        
        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        //Add paragraph to the document
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

        //Close document
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: to my knowledge if you need to have external jars, then you need a package manager i.e., maven or gradle. I suggest maven as a start. Its better to have an ide too. I'd suggest idea community edition. it is easy to setup and run

Comment: the reason why this error occurs is  because java could not find the jar file of itext. Your location might be off. Try to give an absolute path as location. besides if you develop your code as a project/ have packages in it, you should definitely try an ide. That would be much easier

Comment: Try `javac -cp itext.jar C01E01_HelloWorld.java`.

Comment: @vanje itext 7 is not one-big-jar anymore, the code has been split into multiple jars.

Comment: updated initial thread with maybe some progress but no success via one attempt. I had attempted to follow a youtube itext helloworld with eclipse but I don't see the same options in my ecliplse as the vid had regarding the pom file.

Comment: The last one is *almost* correct, you need to add the path where your compiled class is (which is presumably the local directory, in which case simply add `:.` to your `cp` switch).

Comment: ooh ... more progress ... maybe so now I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at C01E01_HelloWorld.main(C01E01_HelloWorld.java:21) will post full source in main thread in case

Comment: so by changing the string DEST back to a fully qualified path get's me further but now it complains Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory    So now I need to fathom where sl4j should come from and what version is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downloaded slf4j.api, slf4j-log4j12, and log4j using links provided in

[SLF4J: Which .jar files does iText7 need exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410540/slf4j-which-jar-files-does-itext7-need-exactly)

and also downloaded the compiled itext jar files from

https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/latest

I then ran

```
javac -cp kernel-7.1.13.jar:layout-7.1.13.jar:io-7.1.13.jar:slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar:slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:log4j-1.2.16.jar C01E01_HelloWorld.java
```

and then

```
java -cp kernel-7.1.13.jar:layout-7.1.13.jar:io-7.1.13.jar:slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar:slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:log4j-1.2.16.jar:. C01E01_HelloWorld
```

and finally I get the alleged simple hello world pdf....

I've tried maven, eclipse, and now IDEA and failed to get any to "just" work following tutorials or hints .... yet

Comment: But this is java 101: add all the required libraries to your classpath for running a program...

Comment: true, but they are iText library dependencies ... it took more searching to establish what they are called and where to get them.

Comment: Well, the official iText documentation tells you that the simplest way to get started, is to use a dependency manager like Maven or Gradle. If you want to do it in a different way, it is assumed that you are a Java expert and know what you are doing...

Comment: All true in some universe. I am not a Java expert and obviously don't know what I am doing, I tried following examples, tutorials and guidance for: maven, eclipse and IDEA and all failed so far.... For a Hello World example I don't think it should be that hard and should also be able to be done as simple as possible. If you pick up a library (or an alleged simple example) you should have the health warnings of it's specific dependencies.

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope that someone else will be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a decent IDE, like IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.
2. Clone the GitHub repository that contains the examples:

```
git clone https://github.com/itext/i7js-jumpstart
```

3. In IntelliJ, open the `pom.xml` in the directory of the repo that you just cloned. IntelliJ will ask you if you want to open it as a Maven project.
4. In IntelliJ, on the left, you have a tree view of all the files in the project. Go to the file `src/main/java/tutorial/chapter01/C01E01_HelloWorld.java`.
5. Run the example (the `main` method).

Comment: re 3. I get option to open as project or file no mention of maven?

re 4. This appears with a banner saying on left Project JDK is not defined and on right Setup SDK.
If I click on Setup SDK it says Detected SDK's 
java-11-openjdk version 11.0.9
default-jvm version 11.0.9
And a "Add SDK" option that then shows
Download JDK
JDK
Intellij Platform Plugin SDK
Android SDK

In top right of C01E01_HelloWorld.java it has 10 errors and 3 warnings

Comment: Open as project. And you may need to install a Maven extension in IntelliJ, better ask on the JetBrains forums to make sure. Or search on Stack Overflow. This is basic Java development and it is assumed that a seasoned Java developer already knows how to setup their development tools.

Comment: thankyou, I will look into that, I've used for java for eons and never got along with it or it's disparate eco systems, really wish I could just gcc ....